# How to set pandas columns names from a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict like:

```
actions = {0: [0, 1, 2, 4], 
           1: [0, 1, 8, 5, 2, 4], 
           2: [0, 1, 2, 5, 6]}
```

And I would like to create a dataframe where the column names where:

```
state_actions = pd.Dataframe()
  
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [[0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 8, 5, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2, 5, 6]]
Index: []
```

The idea is to have as column names the dict values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=actions.values())
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [[0, 1, 2, 4], [0, 1, 8, 5, 2, 4], [0, 1, 2, 5, 6]]
Index: []
```

Comment: Why downvote, it seems to be what the question asker was looking for?

Comment: Exactly, @Tom Ron, I can't believe it was that simple I was going crazy trying all sorts of things. Thank you!!!! nice and easy!!!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but my guess is it was downvoted because it's a code only answer. Answers, without an explanation are often downvoted. Unfortunately, downvoters rarely follow the answers they downvote (to see if there's an edit), nor leave comments.

Comment: The question was very explicit and direct, in the same way has been the answer. I don't understand why the downvote. In any case, it helped me and I marked it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I downvoted this - to elaborate try: `state_actions[[0,1,2,4]]` or `.loc[..]`

Comment: The only sensible way to make it work is to explicitly set up columns as arrays of the same length, like `pd.DateFrame(columns=[[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]])` and hence create `MultiIndex`

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski There's no reason to apologize for downvoting, particularly for legitimate reasons. So, while the answer works to do what is asked, there are issues using other `pandas` methods when columns are named in this way. Therefore, the answer was downvoted because, while it answers this question, it's not likely to be useful to the community. Is that correct?